# Launch screen imageView not appearing on iPhone 12 in simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, launch-screen

I have a launch storyboard set up on my app, and it consists of a basic imageView with a PNG image from my assets catalog that is the same as background throughout the rest of the app.

Everything was working great until the latest update to Xcode. Now my launch screen is blacked out only on the iPhone 12 devices in the simulator. I have an XR as a physical device, and everything is fine there, as well as the other devices in the simulator.

I have tried placing other images in the imageView to test on the LaunchScreen, and they appear fine on the iPhone 12. Just the image that I am using for background isn't working. I also renamed the file in my finder and brought it into the assets catalog. Still doesn't work.

I have made sure to designate the proper screen as my launch screen under the General Tab in my Target settings as well.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[1- Download iOS 14.0 Support Files](https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport)

2 -Unzip it

3 -Put unzipped folder in into path:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/
```

Restart Xcode

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked. Can you possibly explain why this happened?

Comment: glad to here it worked. :)  I think somehow device support files outdated when xcode upgraded. I was once an issue with real device giving error so it worked for me doing same above.

Answer (score -3):

```
 {
  "title": "2C335585-C46D-47E7-965B-F524EC6841E6.jpg",
  "description": "",
  "imageViews": "12",
  "creationTime": {
    "timestamp": "1659526243",
    "formatted": "3 de ago. de 2022, 11:30:43 UTC"
  },
  "photoTakenTime": {
    "timestamp": "1659525936",
    "formatted": "3 de ago. de 2022, 11:25:36 UTC"
  },
  "geoData": {
    "latitude": 0.0,
    "longitude": 0.0,
    "altitude": 0.0,
    "latitudeSpan": 0.0,
    "longitudeSpan": 0.0
  },
  "geoDataExif": {
    "latitude": 0.0,
    "longitude": 0.0,
    "altitude": 0.0,
    "latitudeSpan": 0.0,
    "longitudeSpan": 0.0
  },
  "url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/oOK8nzTrSKcxo7RMyJOBCn8FSKSPh_Bk2yRpQu9geaOXjdP7qLJCeJ84y6srMx21gJga4-E7cCpmoAfZKXCqDoew9O_WCsnJjl6w7F87",
  "googlePhotosOrigin": {
    "mobileUpload": {
      "deviceType": "IOS_PHONE"
    }
  },
  "photoLastModifiedTime": {
    "timestamp": "1673202471",
    "formatted": "8 de jan. de 2023, 18:27:51 UTC"
  }
}
```